# how to add values from nsstrings in iOS?

Tags: button, ios7, nsstring

I have 5 buttons. Each button has some value like `1,2,3,4,5` in a string named `totalSeats_selected`.
I want to save them into a `nsstring`that shows result like this:
  `nsstring * result = [1,2,3,4,5];`

These values are to used as request for a web service, so it must be in this format to send total number of seats?

So, how to save all these values in `nsstring` on button event?

Comment: Look at the docs for `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.Suppose your string is in integer means use Method 1 .otherwise use Method 2(If your value assigned in NSString).

```
 Method 1:



- (IBAction)Savebtnpressed:(id)sender {

NSMutableDictionary *datadict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


[datadict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[first intValue]] forKey:@"1"];

[datadict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[second intValue]] forKey:@"2"];

[datadict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[third intValue]] forKey:@"3"];

[datadict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[fourth intValue]] forKey:@"4"];

[datadict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[fifth intValue]] forKey:@"5"];

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datadict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSURL *someURLSetBefore =[NSURL URLWithString:@" url "];
[request setURL:someURLSetBefore];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  //    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString * string1=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",string1);

 }
   }

   Method 2:


    - (IBAction)Savebtnpressed:(id)sender {

NSMutableDictionary *datadict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

 [datadict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FIRST] forKey:@"1"];

[datadict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",SECOND] forKey:@"2"];

   [datadict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",THIRD] forKey:@"3"];

[datadict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FOURTH] forKey:@"4"];

 [datadict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FIFTH] forKey:@"5"];


NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datadict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSURL *someURLSetBefore =[NSURL URLWithString:@" url "];
[request setURL:someURLSetBefore];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  //    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  //    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString * string1=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",string1);

}
 }
```

Comment: Ganesh , but i need web services in another class I just know how to save these integers in a nsstring like the way [1,2,3], when I tap button it adds 1 in nsstring like [1] and when i tap button 2, the nsstring must becomes like [1,2]...So it can be possible

Comment: and in its response it also shows on 2 buttons click like : ["1","2"] but i need to print it like [1,2]

Comment: try like this -(IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender {

         NSLog(@"Button Tag is : %i",[sender tag]);

        switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 0:
            // Do some think here
            break;
        case 1:
           // Do some think here
             break;
       default:
           NSLog(@"Default Message here");
            break;
}
 and get your sender in new string and it may possible.