# parsing JSON Data with String in ios

Tags: ios, json, ios7

hai i want to send this url with scanCode string the values of this
 {%@}= {123},{USA111},{UK111},{IND111} ect. how to pass this values to the url

```
NSString * urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://1-dot-digiphoto-01.appspot.com/v1/service/rest/getAlbums/QR/{%@}",scanCode];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (!conn)
{
    responseData = nil;
    NSLog(@"Connection Error");

}
```

Comment: check this link you will get the solution . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485693/how-to-add-values-from-nsstrings-in-ios/25486010#25486010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this function, the method is using `POST` variables:

```
-(NSData *)post:(NSString *)postString url:(NSString*)urlString{

    //Response data object
    NSData *returnData = [[NSData alloc]init];

    //Build the Request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Send the Request
    returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];

    //Get the Result of Request
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (response) {
        NSLog(@"Response >>>> %@",response);
    }


    return returnData;
}
```

And here is how you would use it.

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param=%@", 
                                                  @"{123},{USA111},{UK111},{IND111} "];
NSString *urlString = @"http://1-dot-digiphoto-01.appspot.com/v1/service/rest/getAlbums/QR/";    
NSData *returnData =  [self post:postString url:urlString];
```

Comment: how to use connection delegate methods?

Comment: this is very helpful http://blog.kemalkocabiyik.com/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/